# Display <Key> over 2 <Row> in CustomKeyboardView?

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I made custom keyboards for my application based on this amazing research from Marteen Pennings : http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

It's working great.

I want to display a OK key in the same way the 'Enter' key is built on most hardware keyboard : big and 2 rows height.

Any idea on how to do that ? Setting the key height to be double height is not working, the key is half displayed outside the screen (bottom).

EDIT: 
My keyboard bottom rows

```
    <Row>
    <Key android:codes="87"    android:keyLabel="W" android:keyWidth="10%p" android:horizontalGap="20%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="88"    android:keyLabel="X" android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="67"    android:keyLabel="C" android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="86"    android:keyLabel="V" android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="66"    android:keyLabel="B" android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="78"    android:keyLabel="N" android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="-6"    android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_done_48" android:keyWidth="20%p"/>
</Row>
<Row >
    <Key android:codes="-5"     android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete" android:keyWidth="20%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="32"    android:keyLabel=" " android:keyWidth="50%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="-3" android:keyLabel="OK" android:keyWidth="30%p" />
```

I wish the left and right key of the last row expand on the upper row.

Edit : I post a picture to explain my distress : [image: You can see the 'delete' key has empty space above and I want this delete key to claim it]

Solved : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to place your 'OK' key in 4th row intead of the last row and set it as double heigh?

Comment: OMFG ! Thank you ! 
        "Setting the key height to be double height is not working, the key is half displayed outside the screen " and I did not even think putting it at the upper row...

Comment: it does not provide an T-bone shape key but this is good enough :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked! If I discover how to shape it, I'll let you know.